# Restrict arguments and error check

Tags: python

How do I restrict start and end to be multiples of 5? I need to restrict the offset range to be 5 bytes (multiples of 5). If the offset range is invalid, I want to code to quit.

```
start = args.packet_start
end = args.packet_end

try:
  print("Beginning copying of holter data...")

  # Output the specific holter data
  output_file = open("copied_holter.ecg", 'w')

  # Read part of holter file into memory
  holter = open(args.filename, 'rb')
  holter.seek(start)
  data = holter.read((end+1)-start)
  output_file.write(data)

  # Close the file streams
  holter.close()
  output_file.close()  

 except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   print("Exiting program, due to exception.")
   exit(1)

 print "Finished data copying operations!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if start % 5 != 0:
    exit(0)
```

And you can do the same for end.  If start doesn't divide 5 evenly, it will have a nonzero value modulo 5 and therefore your script will exit.  I use the exit code zero, though you may opt for something different.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the modulo operator `%` should do the trick.

```
start = args.packet_start
end = args.packet_end
if not start % 5 or not end % 5:
    raise Exception
```